# How to configure and track properties for the events in the Google Analytics

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking

Would like to add properties to the events in the Google Analytics, the same way as doing it in the Mixpanel. How can I do it?

Generally, what I need to have is for example if I have "Search button" event and its properties: destination, start_date, end_date, group_size

Then I want to see the group size values for the search button and even to connect it to the GOAL.

How can I do all these?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you use - ga.js, gtag.js hardcoded or GTM?

Comment: Hi @Ms.Easy we use Segment tool to connect to the GA